# lightning:input shaped oval when used with size xx-small in iPad

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am using lightning:icon as:

```
<lightning:layout aura:id="uploadProgress" class="slds-hide">
    <lightning:layoutItem class="{!v.showCompleteIcon ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide'}" size="12" largeDeviceSize="2" mediumDeviceSize="2" smallDeviceSize="2">
             <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="xx-small" alternativeText="Done" />
     </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

This is rendered in oval shape in iPad and even a bit in browsers. Is this some known issue, couldn't find any reference in salesforce forum. Or can there be any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a SLDS bug: I noticed that the "oval shape" issue happens if you use `lightning:icon` and scale it below `size="small"`